# Telegram Client API

Tags: python, api, telegram

форумчане. У меня такой вопрос. Реализую сбор сообщений из чата telegram и записываю их в формате json `

```
for message in messages:
            all_messages.append(message.to_dict())
        first_record_number = messages[len(messages) - 1].id
        total_messages = len(all_messages)
        if total_count_limit != 0 and total_messages >= total_count_limit:
            break

    with open('channel_messages.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
        json.dump(all_messages, outfile, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False, cls=DateTimeEncoder)`
```

Как записывать лишь те сообщения, в которых присутствуют определенные слова ?

Запись в таком формате:

```
{
    "_": "Message",
    "id": 62,
    "to_id": {
      "_": "PeerUser",
      "user_id": 900804548
    },
    "date": "2020-07-21T08:25:59+00:00",
    "message": "ioc love belarus",
    "out": true,
    "mentioned": false,
    "media_unread": false,
    "silent": false,
    "post": false,
    "from_scheduled": false,
    "legacy": false,
    "edit_hide": false,
    "from_id": 782177156,
    "fwd_from": null,
    "via_bot_id": null,
    "reply_to_msg_id": null,
    "media": null,
    "reply_markup": null,
    "entities": [],
    "views": null,
    "edit_date": null,
    "post_author": null,
    "grouped_id": null,
    "restriction_reason": []
  },
```

Comment: Регуляркой пройтись по содержимому, если нашли хотя бы одно слово, записывать, иначе - нет

Comment: а можно подробнее ? Никогда не сталкивался с регулярками

Comment: А где в приведённом jsonе надо искать эти слова? Если только в "message", то достаточно проверить `if 'love' in json.message`. А для регулярок в питоне есть специальный модуль `re`

Comment: выдаёт ошибку module 'json' has no attribute 'message'

Comment: `json` в моём примере это абстрактное название вашего json-a :) То есть `json.message` должен быть питоновской строкой "ioc love belarus"

Comment: не выходит, я беру all_mesages и преобразую в json: x = json.dumps(all_mesages). Далее обращаюсь в x.message и выдаёт ошибку ('str' object has no attribute 'message').

Comment: Пажждите, вот вы показали "Запись в таком формате", это json, так? Где в этом джсоне вам нужно найти слова? В строке `"ioc love belarus"` или где-то ещё? Если в этой строке, то для начала вам надо её получить. Вы знаете как это сделать? Если да, то для полученной строки уже вызываете `if word in s`, где `word` - проверяемое слово, `s` - полученная строка

Comment: да, в это строке. Вот проблема в получении это строки. Уже второй день не могу въехать как это делается.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16129652/13970074

Comment: спасибо за помощь, но походу я безнадёжен ) не получается и всё тут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете записать каждое сообщение, которые вам приходит. А после его обработать через модуль re.

Допустим вы определили исходный перечень слов, по которым вам нужно записать сообщение.
Однако помните, что это плохой способ. Если вы посмотрите на список ниже, слово диван некорректно указано. И в этом случае все сообщения, в которых корректно указано это слово , записаны не будут!

```
msg_list = ['пиво', 'диванэ', 'кофе', 'мотор']
```

Далее определяем получения сообщения. Для того, что бы увидеть текст сообщения пользователя используйте message.text. так же в ответе json можно записать и номер телефона и ФИО.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):

    for item in msg_list:
        if item in message.text:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'я записал слово "{message.text}"')
    
    
    user_message = message.text
    ### your logic parse tring by 're' module
```

Не забудьте реализовать запись сообщения, которое было отредактировано.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но у меня client api, а не bot. соответственно реализация будет отличаться.